# Angular ng-click not working inside Javascript quotes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider this `key-value` of an object:

```
 title: 'Available<a class="dayview-action" href="#/app/worker-management/schedule-option/' + $stateParams.id + '/details/' + obj[i].id + '">
<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dayview-action" ng-click="schedule.deleteUserSchedule()">
<i class="fa fa-trash" ></i>
</a>' + moment(obj[i].startTime).format('hh:mm') + ' - ' + moment(obj[i].endTime).format('hh:mm a'),
```

and then there is this simple function,

```
 vm.deleteUserSchedule = function() {
    console.log("ASdas");
  };
```

This all code is in controller file.

My issue is `ng-click` for `deleteUserSchedule()` function is not working.
I can not make this function console. I don't know what is it I am doing wrong or am I missing something.

Actually I'm using [this](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar) calendar. It takes `events` array to display items on calendar. On click of any day cell I switch to day view. In day-view I would like to have a delete button in the title to delete the event. So that is why in `title` key I have placed a delete button, on click of which I would like to perform some functionality to delete.

Any sort of help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Post your entire html and mention how the object is being created. If you are pasting the item in, then you're thinking along the lines of jquery, rather than doing things the angular way.

Comment: How is title inserted into the page? You may need to $compile in order to make directives work

Comment: Wait..I'll edit the description

Comment: You shouldn't store angular code inside JavaScript variables.  Angular won't have any way of knowing that the code exists.  The only way to ensure that angular knows that the code exists is to re-compile the templates.  However, since angular-bootstrap-calendar is a series of directives, it is already compiling the templates, but it isn't treating the `title` as a template.  The only way you'll be able to make this work would be to modify the source of this set of directives.

Comment: Thanks @Claies... Will take a look into the code, see if something can resolve this.

Comment: in fact, the [documentation](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar#custom-directive-templates) states that there is a method to use a decorator to override the template in use for any view, and provide a new template that has the layout you want, including command buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Just put  `ng-click="deleteUserSchedule()"`Instead of  `ng-click="schedule.deleteUserSchedule()"`

Comment: I already tried this. Along with this rather using `vm.deleteUserSchedule` I used `$scope.deleteUserSchedule`, but no success.

Comment: @MoidMohd can you create a plunker for your issue?

Comment: No man, sorry. It won't be possible. It is big project in angular with lots of dependency.

Comment: I got the problem. It is because Angular is not able to compile the `HTML`...I searched about this. Everywhere it is done in a directive. How can I do this is a controller..? Any idea..?

Comment: You should not do dom manipulation in controllers., controllers are to deal with only data

Answer (score 0):

If `vm` is your controller, then you need to add: `vm.deleteUserSchedule()`, otherwise you need to add `deleteUserSchedule()`. So, this depends on your controller implementation.

Another way is this:

```
var vm = this;
function deleteUserSchedule() { 
   ... 
}

vm.deleteUserSchedule = deleteUserSchedule;
```

Comment: I'm using controllerAs syntax. So actually `var vm = this;`

Comment: Try to export it. I wil change my answer to give you an example.